# Wordpress Blog Image Resize

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, blogs

Is there anyone who knows how to adjust the aspect ratio of a blog featured image on a Wordpress blog. The original image is 1500px x 1000px but the front end displays a cut off smaller version of this and only displays fully in a lightbox. I have tried css, changing thumbnail settings and played with theme settings... Unfortunately I cannot share links at this stage the site is still hidden to the public while in development. I have a feeling I will need to correct it with php?

[screenshot of blog images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CawR9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If the code is accessible you may define size in function call as Gozer mentioned. 
OR
`add_filter` for [`post_thumbnail_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/) and modify the post thumbnail HTML as per your need.